# Escape sed command in Jenkins bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Bash script working fine locally, now I am trying to put it in Jenkinsfile to run as its pipeline:

```
    stage('Update Cloudfront'){
      steps {
        sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            YAML_FILE="path/to/values.yaml"
            DATE="$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')"
            wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4 && wget https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
            CLOUDFLARE_NEW=$(awk '{printf fmt,$1}' fmt="%s\n" ips-v4 ips-v6 | paste -sd, -)
            CLOUDFLARE_OLD=$(yq -r .controller.config.proxy-real-ip-cidr $YAML_FILE | sed -E 's/\,37\.16\.11\.30\/32//')
            if [[ "$CLOUDFLARE_NEW" == "$CLOUDFLARE_OLD" ]]; then
              echo "No need to do anything"
            else
              echo "Cloudflare IP ranges change detected, updating Nginx value file"
              CLOUDFLARE_NEW=$(awk '{printf fmt,$1}' fmt="%s\n" ips-v4 ips-v6 | paste -sd, -) yq e '.controller.config.proxy-real-ip-cidr = env(CLOUDFLARE_NEW)' -i $YAML_FILE
              echo "Add third party IP range"
              yq e '.controller.config.proxy-real-ip-cidr +=",1.2.3.4/32"' -i $YAML_FILE
            fi
        '''
      }
    }//end stage('Update Cloudfront')
```

Unfortunately it won't work:

```
WorkflowScript: 73: unexpected char: '\' @ line 73, column 113.
   cidr $YAML_FILE | sed -E \\"s/\,37\.16\.
                                 ^
```

I've tried to escape it with `\\"s/\,37\.16\.11\.30\/32//\\"` etc. but it doesn't work either. I've tried with double and single quotes with no luck.

Comment: Why is the `\,` escaped in the first place? Do you mean `\.` here?

Comment: The comma doesn't need to be backslashed at all, for what it's worth.

Comment: Why does the error show `sed -E \\"` but your provided example shows `sed -E '`? Are you able to access the generated script file before it's run and investigate the contents? The easiest solution would be to get rid of the escaping altogether. e.g. `sed -e 's#,37[.]16[.]11[.]30/32##'`.

Comment: @miken32 sorry, I was trying double and single quotes to escape. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: @daniu No, I meant `,` as this is yet another address range in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid all the escaping by using a character class and different regex delimiters, like so:

```bash
sed -e 's#,37[.]16[.]11[.]30/32##'
```

---

In the event you do need to escape something though, simply doubling the backslash should do it:

```bash
sed -e 's/,37\\.16\\.11\\.30\\/32//'
```

Though, given the number of levels involved here, it might need double escaping:

```bash
sed -e 's/,37\\\\.16\\\\.11\\\\.30\\\\/32//'
```